# NameError: name 'RegexValidator' is not defined

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

This is the code from my models.py.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
     contactNumber = models.IntegerField(max_length = 11, unique = True, validators = [[RegexValidator(regex='^\d{11}$', message='Length has to be 11 numbers including 0', code='Invalid number')]])
     picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'folder_name', default = 'folder_name/default-image.jpg')
     jobTitle = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

When I run `python manage.py sql individual`, I get this error for the contactNumber field.

`NameError: name 'RegexValidator' is not defined`

and this error for the picture field.

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Neither Pillow nor PIL could be imported: No module named Image`

I am new to Python and Django. What should I do to get these two fields corrected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's basic Python that in order to use anything you need to either define it or import it in the current model. In your case, you need to do `from django.core.validators import RegexValidator` at the top of your models file.

For the second one, the error message tells you all you need to know: you need to install Pillow or (less preferably) PIL in your system. The documentation for [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield) mentions this and has the relevant links.

Answer (score 8):

You might need to import it

```
 from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
```

also you need to install Pillow before you can use it